# Error al ejecutar npm run docs-serve, para general la documentación de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, npm

Hace un par de días actualicé npm y desde entonces no puedo ejecutar el comando para correr la documentación de Bootstrap localmente: `npm run docs-serve`

Me da el siguiente error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

La verdad no tengo idea de cómo resolverlo, he desinstalado y vuelto a instalar npm pero sigue dando este error.

Uso Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes hacer un `node --version`? y agregar la version de node a tu pregunta , puede que vas a tener que instalar una version de node mas nueva, o hacer un downgrade al repo que estas intentando instalar

Comment: node version v4.2.6 pero creo que el problema va un poco más allá.

Buscando he encontrado este issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16542. Ahora mismo estoy intentando esta solución https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#if-your-npm-is-broken a ver qué tal, creo que debe funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente la solución la encontré en https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Un saludo.